# Are composite key attributes also foreign keys?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, composite-key

I am working on an assignment and we are supposed to:

[image]

based on this schema:
Underlined = primary key, both underlined = composite key

[image]

My question is for the composite keys, are the two attributes that make up the composite key, as in table Borrower, also considered foreign keys?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to have a composite primary key for a table that are also considered foreign keys. If you do something like the following in SQL it would work properly.

```
CREATE TABLE Borrower
(
    customerID VARCHAR2(10),
    loan_number VARCHAR2(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(customerID, loan_number),
    FOREIGN KEY customerID REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    FOREIGN KEY loan_number REFERENCES Loan(loan_number)
);
```

The important thing to keep in mind is that the data type of the keys in the `Borrower` table have to match exactly the data types of the keys in the `Customer` and `Loan` tables respectively.

Comment: Awesome that makes it much more clear.  I actually had this in my SQL but commented it out because I was not sure about it.